# Problem with a randomized graph contraction algorithm for min cut

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

Hi I am new to c++ and trying to implement a randomized graph contraction algorithm for min cut. The graph is represented as a vector of vectors (data) where the first entry of each vector denotes a vertex and the rest of the entries are the vertices connected to it.
Here is the function for randomized contraction:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> >  contraction (std::vector<std::vector<int> >  data)
{
    srand (time(NULL));
    //choose a random vertex
    int randNum = rand()%(data.size());
    //choose a random vertex connected to the first
    int randNum2 = rand()%(data[randNum].size()-1) +1;

    //loop through all vertices
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        //find the entry corresponding to the second vertex
        if (data[i][0] == data[randNum][randNum2])
        {
            for (int j =1; j <data[i].size(); j++)
            {
                //no self loop
                if (data[i][j] !=data[randNum][0])
                    //add the vertex connection from the second vertex to the first one
                    data[randNum].push_back(data[i][j]);
            }
            //remove the entry for the second vertex
            data.erase (data.begin()+i-1);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
    //all vertices connected to the second vertex are to be connected to the first
        for (int j =1; j <data[i].size(); j++)
        {
            if (data[i][j] == data[randNum][randNum2])
                data[i][j] = data[randNum][0];
        }
    }

    //now the graph has one less vertex
    return data;
}
```

This function is called iteratively in the main:

```
while (data.size() > 2)
{

    data = contraction (data);

}
```

The graph is never contracted down to two vertices. The program terminates after a few iterations without any errors. The number of iterations it goes through are variable, typically 20-30. I cannot figure out why it terminates prematurely, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As you learn to program C++, you should also learn to think like a programmer by describing problems in more meaningful detail. Do you get an error message? What exactly happens?

Comment: Offtopic: there are better random number generators and distributions, like [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).

Comment: @JonathanWood Sorry for the lack of clarity, this is the first question I have asked online and don't really have a clue how to do it properly. I do not get an error message. Given that data.size() = 200, If I add std::cout << data.size() << endl; inside the while loop I get 200 199 198 ... as my output. It never goes all the way down to '2' and the number of iterations it goes through are variable typically terminating at around 170

Comment: @HannibalBarqa Run your program with a debugger attached and it will tell you where exactly the program terminates. It also allows you to step through your program and watch the variables to see where they start to differ from your expectations.